# Find salesman sales between two Excel tabs

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with over 100 salesman's sales on two two tabs. On tab 1 is the person's sales number (ex. 5233) with his monthly sales. On the tab 2 is his quarterly sales. I need to add his actual sales from tab 1 to his quarterly sales from tab 2 under his own sales number.

How do I do this?

```
Tab 1                       Tab 2
5233   120.00           8721  576.00
8721    50.00           5233  1110.00
1954   225.00           1954  850.00
```

Comment: Are you looking to update the entry on Tab 2 to equal its current value plus the Tab 1 value to build the quarterly number each month?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your two columns are A and B, and that you have no header row. If I'm wrong on either of those, you'll need to make adjustments.
In cell Tab 2: C1, enter `=B1+VLOOKUP(A1, 'Tab 1'!A:B, 2, FALSE)`
Then fill down that equation for all other cells in Tab 2 column C.

If you're going to have a Tab 3 for totals instead, then you column A would be all of the sales numbers, column B would be `=VLOOKUP(A1, 'Tab 1'!A:B, 2, FALSE) + VLOOKUP(A1, 'Tab 2'!A:B, 2, FALSE)` and fill down the series.

If you've never used Fill Down before, you can find out how to do it [here](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/867-excel-apply-formula-to-entire-column-row.html)